# Clicking/popping sound supposedly coming from the seat tube area

Tags: saddle, seatpost, noise, clicking

I have a recurring issue with an annoying sound that seems to come from the seat tube/post area. Upon riding on bumpy or rough roads, I can hear a clicking sound whose rhythm seems to follow the contour of the bumps. So, for example, riding over cobblestones will result in a more dense series of clicks; a couple of bumps placed at a short distance between each others will result in two clicks. So far I have: cleaned and applied carbon paste on the seatpost (carbon post inside aluminium frame), changed seatpost clamp, my mechanic torqued all the screws (yes also the bottle cages screws) with a torque wrench, applied grease on the saddle rail and in the area where they enter the saddle body, I lubed the seat clamp screw, greased the seatpost rail and screws.

After bringing the bike to the mechanic I thought the problem was solved, but I didn't have to wait too long for a noisy ride. *It seems* that un-tightening and tightening again the seat clamp solves the problem for a short period of time. But it could just be an impression.

What I haven't done so far is: measuring precisely the seatpost diameter, try to insert another seatpost, try with a new seatclamp. While I try all this and before asking my mechanic to have an in depth look at the bike, does anyone have any suggestion on what can possibly cause this annoying noise? Unfortunately the noise is kind of hard to replicate in a stationary situation, but sometimes I could hear it just by lightly tapping the back of the saddle after having sat on it for a long time. The noise in fact occurs also when I'm not seated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From description, your diagnosis is correct. You appear to be doing everything correctly. It is hard to say what else could be the root cause.

One thing I would recommend trying is: **assemble it without carbon grip paste**. Carbon paste helps to grip things better. It is a good solution when you cannot get enought friction and already maxed out the torque allowed by the component manufacturer. But the paste is not a must contrary to what some people believe. If the seatpost does not slip without the paste, try riding without it.

Start by cleaning the seatpost really well (perhaps with alcohol) and also clean the inside of the seat tube. Assemble everything and torque to correct setting. Just go easy on it first and maybe marki position with a marker pen to see if it starts to slip.

I have previously had stem to handlebar interface that used to creak with paste and stoped when I removed the paste from equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed the carbon paste and only applied a new very thin layer. So far so good…

Comment: Just make sure it does not slip. I hope the problem is sorted. Fingers crossed.